# How to I get the destroy action to work with administrative control in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, admin, destroy

I am going through Michael Hartl's book, "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Learn Web Development with Rails".  In the section where he explains how to get administrative access to delete users, I can't seem to get this to work.  The delete link won't show up on the web app, and I am mystified as to why this is occurring.  This is my unfactored code below, which sits in the directory of: app/views/users/index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>

      <li>
        <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
        <%= link_to user.name, user %>
        <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
            | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                          data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
        <% end %>
      </li>

  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

The methods of `current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user)` are methods located in: app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

```
  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user = current_user
  end
```

I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while and have tried many different things to solve the problem, and none of them have worked.  I'm running Rails on Windows 7 using the Rubymine IDE.  The tutorial was done on a Mac OS X operating system, and I'm thinking maybe the problem might be associated with my setup.

Also are there known issues with tests failing using the Windows cmd when running RSpec versus running it on Mac OS X?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you gave to your user admin privileges?

Comment: Unless it's a typo, your `current_user?(user)` method is wrong. Shouldn't you be comparing with `user == current_user` instead of assigning with `user = current_user`?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out what was wrong!

This method was written incorrectly

```
def current_user?(user)
    user = current_user
end
```

The correct method to get the corresponding code above to work is this:

```
def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
end
```

Thank you for all your input!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your controller you're calling the destroy action in your controller. Your code looks fine thus far and I'm assuming you're not using cancan for authorization.

In view file

```
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
 <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.destroy

  respond_to do |format|                                                                        
   format.html { redirect_to users_path }                                            
   format.json { head :no_content }                                                            
  end     
end
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it still isn't working.  The html isn't properly displaying when I try it in my original way and the way you suggested.  The page should look like this link: http://railstutorial.org/images/figures/index_delete_links_rails_3_bootstrap-full.png) . I'm currently getting a page that looks like that minus all the delete links beside each name.  Do you have any idea why the html on the page might not be displaying?